Integration measure for a strange substitution
I have a 2D integral over a momentum vector, i.e. $\int dp_x dp_y$ and the substitution for this is given by
$$ \xi = |\vec{p}| + |\vec{p} + \vec{q}| , \, \, \, \eta = |\vec{p}| - |\vec{p} + \vec{q}|$$
where we have $\vec{q} = (q_x,0)$. This substitution is simplifying the integrand, but this is not my issue here. It actually is the integration measure, which is supposedly
$$ dp_x dp_y = \frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{4\sqrt{(\vec{q}^2 - \eta^2)(\xi^2 - \vec{q}^2)}} d\xi d\eta. $$
My idea was of course to find the Jacobian for this substitution, for which you need $p_x$,$p_y$ in terms of $\xi$, $\eta$. As you see, this is not so easy for this case, so I thought that maybe this is doable with an implicit substitution, as was shown in the answer here: Jacobian of implicit functions.
However, for this case, at least I was unable to come to the correct result. If you could help me out with this one I'd be very grateful.
In case some more context is needed, this is a integral on my Quantum Field Theory problem set, but this point is strictly about the math behind the integration measure. Another identity regarding this problem is
$$ \cos(\theta_{p,p+q}) = \frac{2q^2 - \eta^2 - \xi^2}{\eta^2 - \xi^2}, $$
but I dont think it's necessary for the substitution or transformation alone. If more context is needed, feel free to let me know.

Why did you delete and ask this question again? I was in the middle of typing my answer for you on your old post. It is highly inappropriate to delete and re-ask a question solely to get more attention for it

I thought that since I messed up the one crucial piece of information in the first equation, this wasn't going to get any answers, so I thought I'd do it again. Unfortunate timing from.my side. I will not do it again, ever, my mistake.

Every MSE post (in fact every SE post) has an edit button for a reason. Hint: try
$$
d\xi= \frac{p_x,dp_x+p_y,dp_y}{|\vec{p}|}+\frac{(p_x+q_x),dp_x+(p_y+q_y),dp_y}{|\vec{p}+\vec{q}|}
$$ and see what comes out.

Thank you. I tried this by doing it also for $d\eta$ (only one minus sign), which allows to simplify $d\xi d\eta$ with the third binomial but for me it doesn't lead to anywhere, I get indeed terms with $dp_x dp_y$ but there also are terms with $dp_x^2, dp_y^2$. If this is the correct way, I'll try further. So far I think I#m either stuck or wrong. I can show my calculation steps if needed.
